# Example where inverse of $(Ku)(x) = \int_0^1 k(x, y) u(y) dy$ is not bounded requested

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, inverse, unbounded-operators

> Define the operator $K$ on $L^2[0,1]$ by $(Ku)(x) = \int_0^1 k(x, y) u(y) dy$ where $k$ is a real-valued bounded continuous function with $k(x, y) > 0$. Consider the problem $Ku = f$. Let $X$ be the set of all $f \in L^2[0, 1]$ such that a unique solution $u = K^{-1} f$ exists. can we be assured that there is a constant $C$ such that $\|K^{-1}f\| \leq C\|f\|$ for all $f \in X$?

If $X$ is complete the answer is yes ($K$ is not only bounded but compact; apply the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem)). Suppose $X$ is not complete. I suspect the answer is no but I cannot think of any example that would show that $K^{-1}$ is not bounded. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with the answer is yes ? If $K$ is compact then $K^{-1}$ is unbounded. This is the case with $k(x,y) = 1_{0 < x < y}$, $K u(x) = \int_0^x u(y)dy$, $K^{-1}v(x) = v'(x)$

Comment: The answer is trivially yes if $K$ is not one-to-one, as then $X$ is empty.  Otherwise, no: a compact operator on an infinite-dimensional space never has a bounded inverse.

Comment: A compact operator is necessarily bounded. Apply the bounded inverse theorem and you get that $K$ has a bounded inverse when defined on a Banach space and has an inverse.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem

The operator used by reuns is not continuous and thus does not count.

$X$ is empty if $K$ is not one-to-one? Couldn't there be a proper subset where unique solutions don't exist?

Comment: [Bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem) is a very strong assumption. Try $\displaystyle k(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2i \pi n y} e^{-n} e^{2i \pi n x}, \quad K u(x) = \int_0^1  \frac{u(y)}{e^{1-2i \pi(x-y)}-1}dy$. Can you compute its inverse ?